# Is there a way to draw an arc in python with starting and ending points and angles?

Tags: python, math

I am trying create an arc in python defined by two points marking the beginning and end of an arc. Both the starting and ending points should have an angle. I am hoping to create a list with X and Y coordinates in a tuple as a set of points drawing out the arc, and plan to have the amount of points within the arc configurable as well.

The reason for doing this is because I want to create a easily configurable camera in a game that travels along an arc defined by two points and their angles. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you wish for more information I’m happy to provide it (:

Comment: Yes, you could look into the relevant equations for bezier curves

Comment: it depends on which graphics library you're using for your game

Comment: `Both the starting and ending points should have an angle` - What does this mean? Perhaps it is worth to show a picture to make things more clear.